# Property 'registerPlugins' does not exist on type 'typeof FullCalendarModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

Trying to integrate fullcalendar into my Angular 15 project and following this:

Error: src/app/views/pages/takvim/takvim.module.ts:18:20 - error TS2339: Property 'registerPlugins' does not exist on type 'typeof FullCalendarModule'.

```
FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  // register FullCalendar plugins
  dayGridPlugin,
  interactionPlugin,
]);
```

package.json

```
"fullcalendar": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.8",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.8",
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

import { TakvimRoutingModule } from "./takvim-routing.module";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { SweetAlert2Module } from "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2";
import { TableModule } from "primeng/table";
import { ButtonModule } from "primeng/button";
import { NgSelectModule } from "@ng-select/ng-select";
import { TakvimComponent } from "./takvim.component";
import { FullCalendarModule } from "@fullcalendar/angular"; // must go before plugins
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid"; // a plugin!
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction"; // a plugin!
import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from "ngx-perfect-scrollbar";
import { CalendarModule } from "primeng/calendar";
FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  // register FullCalendar plugins
  dayGridPlugin,
  interactionPlugin,
]);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [TakvimComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TakvimRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    FeahterIconModule,
    CalendarModule,
    SweetAlert2Module.forChild(),
    TableModule,
    ButtonModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    FullCalendarModule, // register FullCalendar with you app
  ],
})
export class TakvimModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm add component.ts

> plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],

```html
 calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    locale: "tr",

    dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // bind is important!
    eventColor: "#378006",
    eventBackgroundColor: "#FF8C00",
    selectable: false,
    themeSystem: "bootstrap",
    buttonText: {
      today: "Bugün",
    },
    events: [],
  };
```

**This is how I solved your problem**